# How to query classes with edges in orient Db?

Tags: orientdb

[image]

My problem is, how can I query “Chat”  table to retrieve person’s details in Profile Table.

`ParticipatinIn` edge started from Person to chat.
`HasProfile` Edge came started person to Profile.

Please Help me to solve this..

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this structure

[image]

You can use a query like this :

```
select name, person.name, person.out("hasProfile").name as profile from (select name, in('ParticipatinIn') as person from Chat unwind person) unwind profile
```

[image]

If you use traverse, if a person is a part of two different Chat, you got that person only one time.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With this schema:

[image]

Try this:

```
select name, in('HasProfile').name as Person, in('HasProfile').out('ParticipatingIn').name as Chat from Profile
```

This is the output:

[image]

If you don't like see the bracket you can use the unwind command:

```
select name, in('HasProfile').name as Person, in('HasProfile').out('ParticipatingIn').name as Chat from Profile unwind Person,Chat
```

This is the output:

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
select name, in('ParticipatingIn').name as  Person, in('ParticipatingIn').out('HasProfile').name as Profile from Chat
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
traverse * from Chat
```

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards.

Comment: Thanks.. but i need to query from Chat class

Comment: i think traverse will work.. but cant write query using it.. if you now pls let me hoe to do it using "traverse"

Comment: I don't think the traverse is made for your case but, anyway I edited my answer